# Autofac in console applications (convention)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, autofac

I would like to use Autofac in console application. It is my really first usage. Before that I was using it in ASP.NET MVC only. In MVC project I can setup Autofac in Global.asax, inject IService to controller and we can say more and less it works.
In console application I do it like below:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set;}

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Container = Container.Configure(); // here I have all necessary objects set
         // now I can use it in Main method as:
         using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
         {
             scope.Resolve<ISomething>();
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see usage of it is simple in just Main method. How about using it in external class? Let say I would like to create class Cat, and inside that use Autofac. should I pass to contructor object Container from class Program? E.g.:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(Program.Container, "Molly");
```

Or maybe I should create IContainer inside Cat class?

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only your console application really needs to know about AutoFac, otherwise you're falling onto the service locator pattern, which is often considered an anti-pattern. Instead, your application should follow this pattern:

```
//in your console application
using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    IServiceservice = scope.Resolve<IService>();
    service.Execute();
}

class SomeService : IService
{
    readonly ISomeDependency _dependency;

    public SomeService(ISomeDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _dependency.DoSomething();
    }
}

interface IService
{
    void Execute();
}
```

Notice I never actually call a constructor. I make it a habit to never "new up" an object unless that object is just a POCO (contains only data, no logic).

Note that `ISomeDependency` can itself depends on 0 or more other classes, which it takes via constructor injection. Since AutoFac created the `IService`, and all of its dependencies, including `ISomeDependency`, all of `ISomeDependency`'s dependencies will also be initialized, and so forth all the way down. A good video demonstrating this concept is Miguel Castro's [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412).

Comment: mason, thank you for your valuable answer. I would like to extend my problem from first post. As you wrote we can create any object INSIDE main method. What in case I would like to use Autofac in other class?
Let's say I have class

`public class EmployeeService
{
  public Employee GetEmployee(decimal id)
 {
    // here I would like to use some other service: inject using AutoFac.
   // should I create here again Container object and then:
 // using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope()) { ... }
 }
}`

Comment: @cube I don't understand what you're asking now. Yes, you can create an instance of an object via AutoFac and inject things via constructor injection.

Comment: I get confused with my understaning. However you answered on my doubts. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I created this dotnet core console app template with autofac dependency injection configure, this would save your precious time for some repetitive job everytime setting up a new project. Install via nuget, hope it works well for you.

https://medium.com/@mrkevin.wang/create-a-dotnet-core-cosnole-app-template-with-autofac-dependency-injections-60e09f27df17?source=friends_link&sk=d831e88acc36319e2a43e8c7dac70238